# Execute a C# method from html Razor page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing a simple .NET Core Razer project based on this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/

I've created 2 models related in one-to-many relation, just like header-detail. I got header which, after clicking, views all it's details. I would like a button for each of those detail rows that takes it 1 up or 1 down in order. I've created a method in Index.cshtml.cs that does it, but now I need to run this method from Index.cshtml. I tried something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RuleStepMoveUp() {

        var RSO = '@Model.RuleStepMoveUp()';
        alert(RSO);
    }

</script>
```

and there's a button to execute it:

```
<td>
      <input type="button" onclick="RuleStepMoveUp()" value="Get Message" />
      <p></p>
</td>
```

for each of the details, but it doesn't work. RuleStepMoveUp() method executes everytime the page is loaded, and the page fails with error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>   WZI_Konfigurator.Pages.Rules.Index_Page+d__15.MoveNext()
>   in Index.cshtml
>   + 
>   28.        @foreach (var item in Model.Rule.Rules)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Rule.Rules)
        {
            string selectedRow = "";
            if (item.RuleID == Model.ID)
            {
                selectedRow = "success";

            }
            <tr class="@selectedRow">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RuleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stage)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResultColumn)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-id="@item.RuleID">Select</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.RuleID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.RuleID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.RuleID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
```

Even though it loads fine when the JS script is not there.

Right now C# method does the update on one, hardcoded, detail entity to make sure it's working. In the future I will just pass detailID in RuleStepMoveUp method, so that's why there are no parameters.

[That's how the page looks after I deleted the JS function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us4Xf.jpg)

So, how should I approach this to execute the C# method only when the "Get Message" button is clicked? Also, is there a nice and smooth way to update the table for Rule Steps without refreshing the page?

Comment: Server Side Functions can only be executed through "Actions", and Actions can only be executed through HTML Requests, either by reload, or by AJAX

Comment: Ok, but this method is clearly being executed when the page loads, (it sets No column to 0 in the screenshot) it's just that I don't know how to execute it only after clicking the button

Comment: I tried this:

'function RuleStepMoveUp() {

        $.get("/Index/RuleStepMoveUp", function (data) {
            $("p").html(data);

        });
    }'

and changed my method to public ActionResult RuleStepMoveUp(), but nothing happens after clicking the button. Did I pass correct path to the controller in $.get()?

Comment: It's still hard to say for me, but your javascript call looks quite good. You should get clearer understanding of what happens on the client and what on the server side. It might help to start with different function names, e.g. your javascript should be "runRuleStepMoveUpOnServer()" and your Controller Action "RuleStepMoveUp". Check the Web Browser console (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools - F12) for possible errors and you can also examine the execution of the AJAX in the "Network" Tab. You should see the method executed in the background when the button is clicked, and find accidental submits

Comment: @thmshd
thanks, console says that RuleStepMoveUp C# Action was not found, so I guess I'm not referencing it correctly. It's a standard EF scaffolded setup:
Pages 
      Rules
             Index.cshtml
                     Index.cshtml.cs

Index is the page on which Rules are viewed, and Index.cshtml.cs has 
public ActionResult RuleStepMoveUp()

Comment: `'@Model.RuleStepMoveUp()';` is razor code. Its executed on the server before the view is passed to the client. Once on you browser, you cannot execute that method (it exists on the server, not the client). You need to make an ajax call to call a server method that executes that code.